# How can you change the curve resolution of hair particles?

Tags: particles

How can I change the curve resolution of hair particles?  It seems that by default, hair consists of 4 segments.  Which is fine most of the time, but for long hair this does not work at all, as in this picture.

[image]

The *segments* spinner at the very top of the particle settings does not accomplish this, contrary to what one would think from the name and tooltip: *"Number of Hair Segments"*.

Comment: Maybe a bug. I think that used to work.

Comment: I found the same issue, I hope someone has a solution to this

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are three different settings which control this:

[image]

- *3D view > Particle edit mode > Tool shelf > Options > Draw*. This setting affects the curve resolution in the 3D view only while in particle edit mode.
- *Properties > Particle settings > Render > Steps* This setting controls the number of steps in the final render.
- *Properties > Particle settings > Display > Color* This setting controls the number of steps in the viewport, outside of particle edit mode.

The [*Segments*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Particles/Hair) setting at the top of the particle settings controls the number of *control vertices* there are, however doesn't affect the number of *interpolation steps*. Think of this like scaling an image up with *Nearest* interpolation; you end up with more pixels, but the result is not smoothed.

Answer (score 3):

You should also check the influence of the *Children* settings in the *Kink* section are different types of periodic offset to choose from:

Increase the frequency slider (number of waves) and adjust the amplitude (strength of waves)

[image]

[image]

- [Cycles hair rendering](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Hair_Rendering)